# Calling a Vue method in another view instance from v-on:click on the same page?

Tags: html, vue.js

I am integrating Vue into my site and I have a couple of instances on my page. I would like to call a method in the second instance when clicking on a button in the first.

```
<div id="app">
        <div class="sc_menu_btn" v-on:click="menu_mobile.show_menu()"></div>
    </div>

var app_1 = new Vue({
            el: '#app'
})

var menu_mobile = new Vue({
            el: '#mobile-menu',
            data: {
                isActive: false
            },
            methods: {
                show_menu: function () {
                    this.isActive = true;
                },
                remove_menu: function () {
                    this.isActive = false;
                }
            }
        })
```

The above doesn't work however If I place a method in app_1 and call that and that in turn calls show_menu() it works.

```
show_mobile_menu: function() {
                    menu_mobile.show_menu();
                }
```

Any idea why I can't call it directly from the html.

Comment: You can dispatch window event on first app and listen it to second

Comment: See example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-chatelet-hmnhv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.